# How to efficiently sync user's Facebook list of friends with the datastore in App Engine (Java)?

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-datastore

I am building a Facebook app on Google App Engine in Java. Every time a user (old or new) comes to my app, I need to ensure that the current list of user's friends in Facebook is exactly maintained in my datastore. I get the latest list of friends from Facebook Javascript API (FB.api), and I have a list previously created/updated in the datastore. I have two approaches in mind to sync the list in the datastore:

1. Delete the entire list of friends of the user in the datastore and insert all the friends (as per the list coming from FB Javascript API) afresh.
2. Compare the list of friends that I get from FB with the list of friends I have in the datastore: find the new friends in the list from FB (who are not there in the datastore) and add them to the datastore. Secondly, look for friends who are present in the list in datastore but not present in the list coming from FB (the user may have unfriended some users, and then delete them from the datastore.

**Which of these two approaches is more efficient, faster and lower in datastore read/write costs?**

Please see below the code I have for the second approach:

```
//Get user's friend list from the datastore
if (!newUser) { //Only old users will have existing friends in the datastore, so no need to do this for new users
    List<String> DSfriendsIdList = new ArrayList<String>(); //List for keeping the ids of friends in the datastore
    Query DSFLquery = new Query("Friend", userKey); //Datastore Friends List query
    List<Entity> DSFriendListEntities = datastore.prepare(DSFLquery).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
    if (!DSFriendListEntities.isEmpty()) {
        for (Entity dsfle : DSFriendListEntities) { //Build a Set of id's from the entities from the datastore
            DSfriendsIdList.add((String) dsfle.getProperty("id"));
        }
        Set<String> FBfriendsIdSet = new HashSet<String>(); //Set to hold ids coming from Facebook
        Set<Entity> FriendsToBeSaved = new HashSet<Entity>(); //Set to hold new friends that will be added to the datastore 
        size = new Integer(req.getParameter("size")).intValue(); //Number of friends coming from Facebook who use this app
        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) { //Run through each friend from the list of friends coming from Facebook
            String FBfriendId = req.getParameter("friends[" + i + "][id]");
            FBfriendsIdSet.add(FBfriendId);
            if (!DSfriendsIdList.contains(FBfriendId)) { //If this friend id is of a new friend
                Filter frndFilter = new FilterPredicate("id", FilterOperator.EQUAL, FBfriendId);
                Query frndUserQuery = new Query("User").setFilter(frndFilter).setKeysOnly(); //...find this friend in the User database
                List<Entity> frnd = datastore.prepare(frndUserQuery).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
                Key friendUserKey = null;

                if (!frnd.isEmpty()) { // A Friend is added only if he is found in User data
                    Entity friend = new Entity("Friend", userKey); //userKey: Key of the current user in the User database
                    friend.setProperty("name", req.getParameter("friends[" + i + "][name]"));
                    friend.setProperty("id", FBfriendId);
                    friendUserKey = frnd.get(0).getKey();
                    friend.setProperty("userKey", KeyFactory.keyToString(friendUserKey));
                    FriendsToBeSaved.add(friend); //Add user's friend

                    friend = new Entity("Friend", friendUserKey);
                    friend.setProperty("name", userName);
                    friend.setProperty("id", userId);
                    friend.setProperty("userKey", KeyFactory.keyToString(userKey));
                    FriendsToBeSaved.add(friend); //Add user as friend's friend
                }
            }
        }
        if (!FriendsToBeSaved.isEmpty()) datastore.put(FriendsToBeSaved);


        //Remove those friends from the datastore who the user may have unfriended on Facebook
        Set<Key> FriendsToBeDeleted = new HashSet<Key>();
        int i=0;
        for (String DSId : DSfriendsIdList) {
            if (!FBfriendsIdSet.contains(DSId)) {
                Key k = DSFriendListEntities.get(i).getKey(); //Get the key of user's friend who will be deleted
                FriendsToBeDeleted.add(k);
                String frndUserKey = (String) DSFriendListEntities.get(i).getProperty("userKey");
                Query frndToBeDelquery = new Query("Friend", KeyFactory.stringToKey(frndUserKey));
                Filter f = new FilterPredicate("id", FilterOperator.EQUAL, userId); //Get the key of Friend where this user is friend of the friend
                List<Entity> frndToBeDelEntities = datastore.prepare(frndToBeDelquery.setFilter(f)).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
                FriendsToBeDeleted.add(frndToBeDelEntities.get(0).getKey());
            }
            ++i;
        }
        if (!FriendsToBeDeleted.isEmpty()) datastore.delete(FriendsToBeDeleted);
    }
} else { //This is a new user, and therefore there are no friends in the datastore of this user
    //Just add all the FBFriends of this user in the datastore
    Set<Entity> FriendsToBeSaved = new HashSet<Entity>(); //Set to hold new friends that will be added to the datastore
    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) { //Run through each friend from the list of friends coming from Facebook
        String FBfriendId = req.getParameter("friends[" + i + "][id]");
        Filter frndFilter = new FilterPredicate("id", FilterOperator.EQUAL, FBfriendId);
        Query frndUserQuery = new Query("User").setFilter(frndFilter).setKeysOnly(); //Find this friend in the User database
        List<Entity> frnd = datastore.prepare(frndUserQuery).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
        Key friendUserKey = null;

        if (!frnd.isEmpty()) { // A Friend is added only if he is found in User data
            Entity friend = new Entity("Friend", userKey); //userKey: Key of the current user in the User database
            friend.setProperty("name", req.getParameter("friends[" + i + "][name]"));
            friend.setProperty("id", FBfriendId);
            friendUserKey = frnd.get(0).getKey();
            friend.setProperty("userKey", KeyFactory.keyToString(friendUserKey));
            FriendsToBeSaved.add(friend); //Add user's friend

            friend = new Entity("Friend", friendUserKey);
            friend.setProperty("name", userName);
            friend.setProperty("id", userId);
            friend.setProperty("userKey", KeyFactory.keyToString(userKey));
            FriendsToBeSaved.add(friend); //Add user as friend's friend
        }

    }
    if (!FriendsToBeSaved.isEmpty()) datastore.put(FriendsToBeSaved);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Is less computationally expensive.  However, it'll cost more on the datastore.  Note that datastore operations are relatively slow, so even though this is less computationally expensive, you can spend a lot of time waiting for RPCs.  If you're not using async datastore operations, this could be slower.
2. Is more computationally expensive, but it'll cost less on the datastore.